# Integral solutions for linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

For $2n^2$ numbers ${a_{ij}} \in \{ 0,1, - 1\}$ $1 \le i \le n,{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} 1 \le j \le 2n$. Please show that the linear system of equations:

$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {{a_{11}}} &  \ldots  & {{a_{1,2n}}}  \\
    \vdots  &  \ddots  &  \vdots   \\
   {{a_{n1}}} &  \cdots  & {{a_{n,2n}}}  \\
\end{array}} \right)\left( \begin{array}{l}
 {x_1} \\ 
  \vdots  \\ 
 {x_{2n}} \\ 
 \end{array} \right) = 0$

has a set of integral solution $c_i$ , $1 \le i \le 2n$ such that not all $c_i$ are $0$ and $\left| {{c_i}} \right| \le n$.

Comment: First you have $x_i$, and then you have $c_i$? What do you really want? Note that your system is underdetermined...

Comment: @J.M. It's sort of crucial that the problem is underdetermined. Since the system has fewer variables than equations, there's definitely a nontrivial solution. Since the system involves only rational coefficients, there's a rational solution as well, which can also be made integral by simple scaling. ($\langle c_i \rangle_{i =1}^n$ is one such integral solution, I guess.) The main part of the problem is that we should now show that there is an integral solution whose coordinate-entries are all small (i.e., bounded by $n$).

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use [Siegel's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel%27s_lemma).